# Taylor Expansion at x=0 of 1/(1-x^4)

Tags: taylor-expansion

What is the Taylor expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x^4}$ at $x=0$? I was told it is $1 + x^4 + x^8$ + ... but the function's derivatives at $0$ are $0$ so shouldn't the Taylor Series at $0$ just be 1?

Comment: The fourth derivative of $\frac{1}{1-x^4}$ at the origin is not zero.

Comment: Be sure to take your derivatives carefully. It would helpful if you included your work so far.

Comment: You both are right. I lost the constant in my fourth derivative and obtained $\dfrac{(-24*65x^4-24*155x^8-24*35x^{12})}{((-1+x^4)^5)}$. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum^\infty_{n=0}x^n
\end{align}
we see that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1-x^4} = \sum^\infty_{n=0}x^{4n}.
\end{align}

Moreover, observe that
\begin{align}
f^{(4)}(x) = -24 \frac{(1 + 65 x^4 + 155 x^8 + 35 x^{12})}{(-1 + x^4)^5}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
f^{(4)}(0)= 24 = 4!.
\end{align}
Likewise, we can show that other than derivatives which are multiples of 4, the other terms are zeros.

Comment: Thank you! I was missing a constant in my fourth derivative and I didn't catch the connection to the geometric series at first. That makes it very intuitive!